# Python - Using "Google AJAX Search" API's Local Search Objects

Tags: python, json, google-api, geopy

I've just started using Google's search API to find addresses and the distances between those addresses. I used geopy for this, but, I often had the problem of not getting the correct addresses for my queries. I decided to experiment, therefore, with Google's "Local Search" (http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/local.html).

Anyway, I wanted to ask if I could use the "Local Search" objects provided by the API within python. Something tells me that I can't and that I have to use json. Does anyone know if there is a work around?

PS: Im trying to make something like this: http://www.google.com/uds/samples/random/lead.html ... except a matrix type deal where the insides will be filled with distances between the addresses.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the docs](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/) say,

> The Google AJAX Search API is a
>   Javascript library that allows you to
>   embed Google Search in your web pages
>   and other web applications. For Flash,
>   and other Non-Javascript environments,
>   the API exposes a raw RESTful
>   interface that returns JSON encoded
>   results that are easily processed by
>   most languages and runtimes.

Python has no trouble processing Json (e.g. with the `json` module in the standard library in 2.6 and better -- there are also several third party ones e.g. for earlier releases, `simplejson` being the direct precursor of today's standard `json`).  So it's all about using the RESTful interface correctly, as for most Google APIs not directly wrapped for this or that non-Javascript language.

The code examples [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje_snippets) are for Flash, Php, Java, Python, Perl -- they all boil down to visiting a specific URL, e.g. with `urllib2` in Python, and processing the returned Json, e.g. with `simplejson` in (pre-2.6) Python.

All the queries in these RESTful code samples are for a web search, but local search is very similar, just start with the request URL with:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&q=...
```

i.e., use `local` in lieu of `web` in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

What are the other parameters for local search --- is there a way to set a N,S,E,W bounding box for the query?
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&q=...